# Jenkins: Get branch from last successful build

Tags: git, jenkins

I am wondering, if Jenkins API allows to retrieve the branch of a git repository, that has been built with the last successful build of a job.

My job has a multi-branch specifier like 'developer-*', so it builds different feature branches.

Now I would like to know, which branch actually has been build by this job lately.

I can use this syntax to retrieve the last successful build with its timestamp.

```
http://localhost:8080/jenkins/view/myview/api/json?depth=2&tree=jobs%5BdisplayName,lastBuild%5Bbuilding,result%5D,lastSuccessfulBuild%5Btimestamp%5D%5D
```

However, I could not find any property name in the API documentation that would give me the branch.

Is that actually possible?

Comment: Hope this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321157/how-to-fetch-the-current-branch-from-jenkins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I can call

```
http://localhost:8080/jenkins/job/$jobname/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json
```

or more precisely for my case

```
http://localhost:8080/jenkins/job/$jobName/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json?tree=actions[lastBuiltRevision[branch[*]]]
```

as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18241221/3271380).

From the response I should be able to use
actions > x > lastBuiltRevision > branch > 0 > name